# Как удалить элемент из словаря если у него в значении массив с одним элементом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict

У меня есть словарь:

```
{'Senior-Разработчик': ['Краков', 'Гордон'],
'монтажник': ['Познер', 'Шумский', 'Филатов'],
'Middle-Разработчик': ['Мурин'],
'web-программист': ['Козлов', 'Борцов', 'Фитисов'],
'Junior-Разработчик': ['Привалов'],
'кассир': ['Иванов', 'Шувалов']}
```

Как удалить элемент из словаря если у него в значении массив с одним элементом?

Comment: приведите в вопросе ожидаемый результат. Что вы подразумеваете под элементом, который нужно удалить - ключ словаря или только значение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = {'Senior-Разработчик': ['Краков', 'Гордон'],
'монтажник': ['Познер', 'Шумский', 'Филатов'],
'Middle-Разработчик': ['Мурин'],
'web-программист': ['Козлов', 'Борцов', 'Фитисов'],
'Junior-Разработчик': ['Привалов'],
'кассир': ['Иванов', 'Шувалов']}

for i in list(a.keys()):
  if isinstance(a[i], list) and len(a[i]) == 1:
    del a[i]


print(a)
```

результат:

```
{'Senior-Разработчик': ['Краков', 'Гордон'],
 'web-программист': ['Козлов', 'Борцов', 'Фитисов'],
 'кассир': ['Иванов', 'Шувалов'],
 'монтажник': ['Познер', 'Шумский', 'Филатов']}
```

Comment: `.keys()` можно не писать, словарь итерируется именно по ключам; `i` - плохое название для не целой числовой переменной, для перебора ключей хорошее название будет, например, `key`

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо) про дефолтную итерацию по ключам и правда забыл